Android Native Hook: dlopen always returns NULL
On Android 12 emulator, I write a so lib injected into the target app which has a lib called libmain.so. I can see the base address of libmain.so by using "cat /proc/self/maps". However, it always return null when I call dlopen("libmain.so", RTLD_LAZY) from my so lib. Did I miss anything? Basically, what I want is to use dlopen and dlsym to get some exported functions address.
